# Make text and button stay on same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make the text and button stay on the same line

**HTML**

```
<div class="server">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="serverinfo"><p><b>Map:</b> ttt_minecraft_b5<br><b>Spillere:</b> 12/24</p>
            <p class="connect"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Koble til</a> </p>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.serverinfo {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.connect {
    text-align: right;
}
```

[**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/ccCpzjXFJe)

Hope you guys understand, can't include a picture

Thank you for all the help!

Comment: the same line as ttt_minecraft_b5 or both of lines?

Comment: @JeanGkol Does it matter? Won't it scale over both? Same line as ttt_minecraft_b5

Comment: you use paragraph for both of them, this makes button set in a new line.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have your link button in a separate p tag. Put the link button anchor tag in the same p tag.

```
<p>text here and stuff <a></a></p>
```

Comment: You would add a margin to the CSS add a margin-left to the anchor tag of like 15px

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
.serverinfo {
margin: 0 0 10px 0;
padding: 4px;
background-color: white;
border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
overflow: hidden;
float: left;
}

.connect {
text-align: right;
float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove connect selector and combine both paragraph tag into one line, as in:

```
<div class="server">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="serverinfo">
                <p><b>Map:</b> ttt_minecraft_b5
                    <br/><b>Spillere:</b> 12/24 
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Koble til</a> 
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<style>
.serverinfo {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

Demo **[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/alicera/fkr2nbn9/)**
Perhaps, that's what you need.

Or, you need it like this below?
Updated [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/alicera/fkr2nbn9/1/)
[image]